# Why my gridview's paging is not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have two gridviews on different pages, with almost the same code, and one is working but the other isn't...

Here's the code of the one that is NOT working:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnablePartialRendering= "true">
     </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="gridview">
          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;" 
           DataKeyNames="id"
           CssClass="gridview" BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
           BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="GrayText"
           CellPadding="1"
           CellSpacing="5"
           HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
           OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
           ForeColor ="Black" RowStyle-CssClass="gridview"
           OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
           ViewStateMode="Enabled" AllowPaging="True" 
           OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="3">
           <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
             <columns>

               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id"  />
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PRIORIDADE" DataField="prioridade" 
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
               <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
               </asp:BoundField>
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SITUAÇÃO"  DataField="situacao" 
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
               <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
               </asp:BoundField>
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RESPONSAVEL" DataField="responsavel" 
                        HeaderStyle-Width="65px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
               <HeaderStyle Width="65px" />
               <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
               </asp:BoundField>
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DATA DE CADASTRO" DataField="dt_cadastro" 
                        DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-Width="60px" 
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
               <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
               <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
               </asp:BoundField>
               <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PREVISÃO DE TÉRMINO" DataField="previsao_termino" 
                        DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" 
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
              <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              </asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PROJETO" DataField="projeto"  
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >          
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              </asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FUNCIONALIDADE" DataField="funcionalidade" 
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              </asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CLUBE" DataField="clube" 
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >

              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              </asp:BoundField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="70px" HeaderText="VISUALIZAR" >
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Button ID="Btn_Visualizar" runat="server" Text="VISUALIZAR" CssClass="Btn_Grid"  Font-Size="7pt" Font-Names="Verdana, Arial"
                            CommandName="visualizar" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />                            
                  </ItemTemplate>
                   <HeaderStyle Width="70px" />
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="66px" HeaderText="ALTERAR">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Button ID="Btn_Alterar" runat="server" Text="ALTERAR" CssClass="Btn_Grid" Font-Size="7pt" Font-Names="Verdana, Arial"
                            CommandName="editar" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   <HeaderStyle Width="66px" />
               </asp:TemplateField>
        </columns>
            <EditRowStyle ForeColor="Black" CssClass="GridViewEditRow" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#6600FF" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                    Font-Size="8pt" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />      
            </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And Here is my `codebehind`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (Session["login"] == null)
      {
         Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
      }
   else
      {
         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
              GridView1.DataSource = _ch.BuscaChamadosAtivos();
              GridView1.DataBind();
            }
       }
 }

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridView1.DataSource = _ch.BuscaChamadosAtivos();            
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Even the `numbers of the pagging` does not shows up...

Obs: Two of these fields will come `ALWAYS` empty... May this be causing me this problem ? I don't think so... But I said anyway.

Comment: Did you define your GridView1_RowDataBound event in your code?

Comment: He would get an error if he didn't

Comment: This may be totally unrelated, but is the ScriptManager on a page supposed to go inside an UpdatePanel?  I had the impression it was supposed to be on the outer page.

Comment: @AnnL. Ohh no, I'm using this to work with AjaxControlToolKit and it's working fine ! I just found out the problem, as soon as possible I'll be posting the solution (I'm a little bussy here at work). Thanks everyone for spent some of your time helping me out =)